# Couldnt pass the cursor list to another method

Tags: android, arrays, cursor

I couldnt use `myid[]` integer list in `onclick` method.

I mean :

I want to get `myid[0]`,`myid[1]`,`myid[2]`...... list values from `populatelist()` 's cursor list

Then I'll be able to use them in `onClick` method like `myid[index]`

```
   @Override
    protected void populateList() {

       Cursor cursorKayit = db.rawQuery(query, null);

       int[] myid = new int[cursorKayit.getCount()];         
       int i = 0;
        while(cursorKayit.moveToNext()){

        myid[i]=cursorKayit.getInt(0);
        String mytitle=cursorKayit.getString(1);
        String mydescription=cursorKayit.getString(2);
        getUITableView().addBasicItem(mytitle, mydescription);
        i++;

        }
        cursorKayit.close();

        }
```

..

```
private class CustomClickListener implements ClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(int index) {


        Toast.makeText(CategoryMenu.this, "item clicked: " + myid[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
```

Comment: I am not a `JAVA` expert, so please pardon my ignorance. I feel `myid` should be in a more global scope i.e. it's current scope is limited to `populatelist` function. Shouldn't it be a part of `CustomeClickListener` to be accessible in `onClick` method?

Comment: If you have a listview then you can implement onItemClickListener and you will get the position in the list as well as the id.